# Need Help With Process to Get Probabilities

Tags: probability

What is the probability of one of two $6$-sided dice to roll at least one $6$?

What is the chance that out of having $7$ children, $4$ are boys and $3$ girls?

I would like to learn the process of finding out.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  For the first you can just write out all the possibilities if you can't think of anything better.

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange. Please read about how to write a good questions: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I appolgize in advance for the answer being so long, it's just that you asked the full process so I explained everything and linked where I thought would be necessary).$$$$
If you want to know the probabilty of getting atleast one roll of 6 out of 2 dice rolls, the simplest approach would be to calculate the probabilty of the [complement event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_event) (complement event means that if some event P means that $x$ happens, then the complement event of p is specifically that $x$ doesn't happen) the complement event of getting rolling 6 atleast once is not rolling 6 at all which is $\frac{5}{6}$ (every number except for 6 can be rolled), because rolling some numbers on two dice rolls are [independent events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)) (the probabilty of one occuring doesn't affect the probabilty of the second occuring) then the probabilty of the event (not rolling a 6) happening twice would be $\frac{5}{6}^2$ = $\frac{25}{36}$.
The probabilty of the complement event of A to occur is 1 - A, so we can coclude that if x is the probabilty of getting 6 on atleast one dice rolls, then $1-x=\frac{25}{36}$ which means that $x=1-\frac{25}{36}=\frac{11}{36}$.

In order to find out the probabilty of having 4 boys and 3 girls we can use the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), which basicly just says that if want some event to happen $k$ times out of $n$ trials and you know that each trial of the event has an equal probabilty and is independent of the outcomes of the other trails, then the probabilty of that is the number of ways to to get a squence which includes $k$ succeses out of $n$ trials (denotated with ${n}\choose{k}$) times the probabilty of the path, we know that the probabilty of having a boy is $\frac{1}{2}$ and the same thing for having a girl. So accoridng to the formula, the probabilty is:
${7}\choose{4}$$\frac{1}{2}^4$$\frac{1}{2}^3=\frac{35}{128}$